# how to pass *args in df.apply()

Tags: python, pandas, partial

I have a function which I want to be able to apply on variable number of columns based on the input.

```
def split_and_combine(row, *args, delimiter=';'):
    combined = []
    for a in args:
        if not row[a]:
            combined.extend(row[a].split(delimiter))

    combined = list(set(combined))
    return combined
```

But I'm not sure how to apply this function to the df, because of the *args. I'm not very familiar with `*args` and `*kwargs` in python. I tried using partial and set axis=1 as below but get the TypeError below.

```
df['combined'] = df.apply(partial(split_and_combine, ['col1','col2']),
                          axis=1)

TypeError: ('list indices must be integers or slices, not Series', 'occurred at index 0')
```

A dummy example for the above code. I want to be able to pass in flexible number of columns to combine:

```
Index   col1        col2            combined
0      John;Mary    Sam;Bill;Eva    John;Mary;Sam;Bill;Eva
1      a;b;c        a;d;f           a;b;c;d;f
```

Thanks! If there's a better for doing this without df.apply. Please feel free to comment!

Comment: What's your expected output? Perhaps apply isn't necessary.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Output is as in the dummy example. I'm expecting a new df column 'combined' with value returned from the function. Please advise if you know how to do this without apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`df.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) docs

> args : tuple
>
> Positional arguments to pass to func in addition to the array/series.
>
> **kwds
>
> Additional keyword arguments to pass as keywords arguments to func.

`df.apply(split_and_combine, args=('col1', 'col2'), axis=1)`

btw you might have some bugs in your function:

```
def split_and_combine(row, *args, delimiter=';'):
    combined = []
    for a in args:
        if row[a]:
            combined.extend(row[a].split(delimiter))
    combined = list(set(combined))
    return delimiter.join(combined)
```